# Button next to a resizable textarea using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to place Reply button right next to the textarea with sort of 9/1 ratio.
I've tried floating the textarea left and button right but I just can't make it right. The button goes either underneath the textarea or becomes too big.

The thing with this is that I don't want to resize my button. I want to keep it the size it is and resize width of the textarea based on the remaining space filled out by the button when resizing the window.

Currently I came up with this but it's rubbish because making a button 10% will narrow it when resizing a window. What can I do to keep the button the same size (BUT NOT FIXED SIZE) and resize the textarea instead?

```css
.group-reply {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.group-reply textarea {
 width: 90% !important;
}

.group-reply button {
  width: 10%;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="input-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6 btm20 group-reply">
      <textarea auto-resize ng-model="vm.model.textarea" name="reply" class="form-control"></textarea>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-reply">Reply</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**@edit** Desired final effect

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flex-d` class instead of `input-group`.

```css
.group-reply {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

textarea{
 min-height: 34px;
 overflow-y: hidden;
}

.btn{
 height: 34px;
 margin-top: auto;
 background-color: #0BC6DD;
 color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="flex-d col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6 btm20 group-reply">
      <textarea auto-resize ng-model="vm.model.textarea" name="reply" class="form-control" style="
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204) !important;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: unset;
    border-radius: 0;
    "></textarea>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-reply">Reply</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, but flex makes it adjust to the height of the textarea which I don't want. I'd like it to stay the same size in the bottom right corner of the textarea. As the textarea becomes taller, button goes further down and alligns with the bottom of the textarea. Check out my edit on the post.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk Added margin-top to auto on button element. Working expected?

Comment: In the plunker it does work but on my page the Reply button stays in the middle of the textarea's height.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk can you share working plunker or screenshot of this issue.

Comment: I've actually made it work by setting the buttons margin to this: .group-reply button { margin: auto 2px 0px; } You might remove the additional stuff you've put it.

Comment: On IE the Reply button expands to the whole height of the textarea unfortunately...

Comment: Reply button doesn't have a fixed height. Added one explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Bootstrap's row and column classes:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="input-group">
      <textarea auto-resize ng-model="vm.model.textarea" name="reply" 
        class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary text-left btn- 
    reply">Reply</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can change the size of your columns to your liking.

Comment: The button and textarea are quite far apart even with col-sm-11 to col-sm-1.

Comment: Use `form-row` instead of `row` for less padding between columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
.group-reply {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display:flex
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6 btm20 group-reply">
      <textarea auto-resize ng-model="vm.model.textarea" name="reply" class="form-control"></textarea>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-reply">Reply</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t7nud6z0/

Comment: As commented below, flex resizes button's height accordingly to the textarea.